Picklist options are not showing in the LWC Datatable
I kindly request don't mark it as a duplicate.
my html code:
        <template>
            <lightning-card title="Opportunity Line Items">
                <template if:true={opportunityLineData}>
                    <c-custom-data-type
                    key-field="Id"
                    data={opportunityLineData}
                    columns={columns}
                    onsave={handleSave}
                    draft-values={draftValues}
                    onrowaction={handleRowAction}
                    hide-checkbox-column></c-custom-data-type>
                </template>
            </lightning-card>
        </template>

my js code:
    import { LightningElement,track,wire,api} from 'lwc';
    import { updateRecord, deleteRecord} from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
    import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
    import { refreshApex } from '@salesforce/apex';
    import { getObjectInfo, getPicklistValues } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
    import OPPORTUNITYPRODUCT_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/OpportunityLineItem'; 
    import DISCOUNT_TYPE from '@salesforce/schema/OpportunityLineItem.Discount_Type__c'; 
    
    import getOpportunityLineItems from '@salesforce/apex/OpportunityLineItemController.getOpportunityLineItems';
    
    const columns = [
    { label: 'ProductLineItemName', fieldName: 'ProductLineItemName__c'},
    { label:'Quantity', fieldName:'Quantity',editable:true},
    { label: 'Sales Price', fieldName: 'UnitPrice', editable:true},
    { label: 'Discount Value', fieldName: 'Discount_Value__c', editable:true},
    {
        label: 'Discount Type',
        fieldName: 'Discount_Type__c',
        type: 'customPicklist',
        editable: true,
        typeAttributes: {
           
            options:{fieldName:"pickListOptions"},
            value: { fieldName: "Discount_Type__c"},
            context:{ fieldName: "Id"}
            
        }
    },
    { label: 'GST %', fieldName: '  GST__c', editable:true},
    
    
    {
        type: "button",
        typeAttributes: {
            iconName: "utility:delete",
            name: "deleteOpportunity",
            variant: "destructive",
            iconSize: "x-small",
            class: "small-button"
        }
    }
    
    ];
    
        export default class OpportunityLineItemsEditor extends LightningElement {
        
        @api recordId;
        
        opportunityLineData=[];
        columns = columns;
        draftValues=[];
        oppLineProp;
        discountTypeOptions=[];
        
        @wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: OPPORTUNITYPRODUCT_OBJECT })
            opportunityProductInfo;
        
            @wire(getPicklistValues, {
                recordTypeId: '$opportunityProductInfo.data.defaultRecordTypeId',
                fieldApiName: DISCOUNT_TYPE
            })
            wiredPicklistValues({ data, error }) {
                if (data) {
                    this.discountTypeOptions = data.values;
                } else if (error) {
                    console.error('Error fetching picklist values', error);
                }
            }
        
        
        @wire(getOpportunityLineItems,{
            opportunityId:"$recordId",pickList:"$discountTypeOptions"
        }) getOpportunityLine(result){
            this.opportunityLineData=result;
        
            if(result.data)
            {
                //this.opportunityLineData=result.data;
                this.opportunityLineData=result.data.map((currItem) =>{
                    let pickListOptions = this.discountTypeOptions;
                    return {
                        ...currItem,
                        pickListOptions:pickListOptions
                        //pickListOptions:picklistOptions
                    }
                });
        
            }
            else if(result.error)
            {
                console.log('error while loading records');
            }
        
        
        }
        
        async handleSave(event)
        {
        
            let records=event.detail.draftValues;
            let updateRecordsArray= records.map((currItem) => {
                let fieldInput = {...currItem};
                return{
                    fields:fieldInput
                };
        
            });
        
            this.draftValues=[]
            let updateRecordsArrayPromise=updateRecordsArray.map((currItem) => updateRecord(currItem));
        
            await Promise.all(updateRecordsArrayPromise);
        
            const toastEvent = new ShowToastEvent({
                title: 'Success',
                message:
                    'Records Updated Successfully',
                    variant:'success'
            });
            console.log('Dispatching toast event...');
            this.dispatchEvent(toastEvent);
            console.log('Toast event dispatched.');
            await refreshApex(this.oppLineProp);
        
        }
        
        async handleRowAction(event) {
            if (event.detail.action.name === "deleteOpportunity") {
                deleteRecord(event.detail.row.Id).then(() => {
                    
                    this.dispatchEvent(
                        new ShowToastEvent({
                            title: 'Success',
                            message: "Record deleted successfully!",
                            variant: 'success'
                        })
                    );
                }).catch((error) => {
                    console.log("error, " + error);
                    this.dispatchEvent(
                        new ShowToastEvent({
                            title: 'Error deleting record',
                            message: error.body.message,
                            variant: 'error'
                        })
                    );
                })
            }
        
            await refreshApex(this.oppLineProp);
        }
        
        }

I'm able to retrieve the picklist values, but the picklist options aren't populating. What would be the workaround to resolve this?

How is this question different from your earlier post?  The title is exactly the same.

Yes it's almost similar but I'm not able to retrieve picklist options. Apart from that, my code is working fine.

Did you resolve the issue, if Yes can you tell me the solution?
